# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ":"

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am running an SQL query from PgAdmin4 which runs successfully, but when i take that same query to run it from my Spring Boot application i have an error " org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ":" "

Here is what the SQL query looks like:

```
SELECT
   student.surname, student.first_name, student.last_name,
   jsonb_pretty(elems)
FROM assessment, jsonb_array_elements(assessment.assessment) AS elems
JOIN student ON student.id = (elems->>'student_id')::uuid
WHERE subject_id = 2
AND academy_year_id =3
AND form_id = 2
AND term_id = 1
AND section_id = 4;
```

And this run successfully from PgAdmin4.

This is my implementation in my Repository

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT\n" +
        "       student.surname, student.first_name, student.last_name,\n" +
        "       jsonb_pretty(elems)\n" +
        "FROM assessment, jsonb_array_elements(assessment.assessment) AS elems\n" +
        "JOIN student ON student.id = (elems->>'student_id')::uuid\n" +
        "WHERE subject_id = 2\n" +
        "AND academy_year_id =3\n" +
        "AND form_id = 2\n" +
        "  AND term_id = 1\n" +
        "AND section_id = 4;")
Object[] getSubjectAssessments();
```

And when my API calls this method i get this error message

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ":"
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: ::uuid means parameter?

Answer (score 4):

JPA can't handle the Postgres specific cast operator `::`.

Use `cast()` instead:

```
JOIN student ON student.id = cast(elems->>'student_id' as uuid)
```

Comment: Thank for the answer,  but now get this error when I used the cast() org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"

Comment: @remove the `)` after student_id (copy & paste error)